# Why is this background property overriden many times?

Tags: html, css

I'm still trying to cleaning up a CSS and trying to understand what the author meant. I always try to understand what someone did because I think that people are clever and if they did something that way, *there must be a reason*.

Usually it's the *name* of the property that changes (`-webkit-box-shadow`, `-moz-box-shadow`, `box-shadow` etc) but here it's the value, and I've never seen that before.

It seems he tried to override this `background` property many times. I've never seen this before. Is it a good or a bad practice, and if it's a bad practice what should be the clean way to write this CSS:

```
.nav.side-menu> li.active > a {
    color: #ff0000;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 -1px 0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #5b6479), color-stop(100%, #4c5566)), #686e78;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#334556, #2C4257), #2A3F54;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#334556, #2C4257), #2A3F54;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#334556, #2C4257), #2A3F54;
    background: linear-gradient(#334556, #2C4257), #2A3F54;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16) 0 1px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16) 0 1px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16) 0 1px 0;
}
```

Here's how PyCharm sees the CSS: only `background: -moz-linear-gradient(#334556, #2C4257), #2A3F54;` is known...

[image: css in PyCharm]

Comment: Overriding usually means browser compatibility issues. Otherwise it might be laziness as well ;)

Comment: @manelgarcia Thank you for your comment... but is it a comment or an anwser? If you could answer with more details, that would be really kind...

Comment: Those are vendor prefixes. More here --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about being the correct answer, that's why I comment, sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: @ovokuro Ok... so why does PyCharm think it's overriden? It's not, is it?

Comment: @I've no idea what PyCharm is, sorry!

Comment: @OlivierPons its browser specific syntax.. So if you view the same page in IE you see a different syntax taken into account.. Usually people write it as they have no control on which browser the end user will use. So the idea is write all the browser compatible syntax so the right one is picked from the browser ...

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I know all of this, but usually it's the *name* of the property that changes (`-webkit-box-shadow`, `-moz-box-shadow`, `box-shadow` etc) but here it's the value, and I've never seen that before. I'll update my question, because I think I wasn't clear enough

Comment: PyCharm shows that It is overridden because it is overridden, but only the parameter that the browser recognises is used. Check out http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ that creates gradients with prefixes in this way. It's pretty standard.

Comment: It seems that the problem comes from the `, #2A3F54` after the definition

Comment: Although, saying that some of the prefixes may now be obsolete as browsers have gradient compatibility now, though older versions will not. You can use a tool like css-nano to clean up css and remove obsolete prefixes.

Comment: @Sarcoma Very nice suggestions, I'll try css-nano ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [vendor prefixes](https://www.thoughtco.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867), the dev doesn't tried to override a property many times, he's doing this because of the browser compatibilities with some css propeties that are experimental or uncommon to the css the browser supports at the version the developer was using.

So `-moz-`is for Mozilla Firefox, `-webkit-` is Chrome, Safari and Opera (newer versions), `-ms-` is Microsoft Explorer and Edge and `-o-`is for Opera alone in older versions.

When you come across something like this is like the code is saying to the browser "hey, i know maybe you know this property, i know it by the name x but maybe you know it by the name -vendor-x"

But see the link for more information. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Your link is for Spanish people :) ... But I'm wondering why does PyCharm think it's overriden? It's not, is it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, there's a new link. It shows as if it has overridden the css, even if you go to your browser developer console it'll show that way, but it's more like eliminating code that doesn't fit that browser. If there's no vendor prefixes some css may not render on specific browsers.